# Create bean using applicationContext calling noArgs constructor even after passing the args in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have a class with no args constructor and constructor with args as below.

```
@Component
public class DataValidator  {
    private DataValidator(){
        System.out.println("Calling no Args const");
    } 


    public DataValidator(String id){
        log.info("ID is: "+id);
    }

}
```

StartValidator.java

```
@Component 
public class StartValidations extends BaseValidator {


    public void start() {
       DataValidator data = applicationContext.getBean(DataValidator.class,"123");
    }
}
```

When I call the `start()` function, it's printing `Calling no Args const` instead of `ID is: 123`. Why its calling the no args constructor even after passing the args to getBean method.

Comment: Only one annotated constructor per-class can be marked as required, but multiple non-required constructors can be annotated. In that case, each is considered among the candidates and Spring uses the greediest constructor whose dependencies can be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, whenever you declare component, bean is created using one constructor for autowiring (the only constructor available or picks one after comparing available constructors). I would suggest to

1) use setter injection instead

2) remove `@Component` and rely only on your configuration

3) place `@Value("${placeholder}")` before `String id` in your bean, and mark that constructor for autowiring, so as it is chosen.

In addition, please check [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216277/bean-with-multiple-constructors-in-java-based-spring-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case in class DataValidator, since multiple constructors were specified and none of then were marked `@Autowired(required=true)`. So Spring has used the default constructor to create the Bean. As a result when you are calling

```
applicationContext.getBean(DataValidator.class,"123");
```

You are getting the Bean which is created using Default constructor.

Only one annotated constructor per-class can be marked as required, but multiple non-required constructors can be annotated. In that case, each is considered among the candidates and Spring uses the greediest constructor whose dependencies can be satisfied

Answer (score 1):

Use @Scope("prototype") over DataValidator class.This scopes a single bean definition to have any number of object instances.

Find the reference here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataValidator  {
    private DataValidator(){
        System.out.println("Calling no Args const");
    }
    public DataValidator(String id){
        log.info("ID is: "+id);
    }
}
```